# Parallel test process per assembly with NUnit 3 and TeamCity NUnit Runner

Tags: nunit, teamcity, nunit-3.0

I have a project with a large number of test assemblies. According to the documentation, NUnit should be able to automatically run a *process per assembly*, in parallel, and I can control this with the `--process` and `--agents` command line parameters.

However, when I run my tests using TeamCity, the TeamCity test runner, TeamCity calls nunit3-console *once per assembly*, sequentially. Obviously, this means that my tests do not run in parallel. How do I get TeamCity to run the tests in parallel ?

*Edit*:
This is the command line that TeamCity uses to invoke nunit3-console.exe:

```
C:\BuildAgent\tools\nunit-console_v3.6.1\bin\nunit3-console.exe E:\BuildAgent\temp\buildTmp\FnDjYhVytEZUfv5WbP6BFfjbQiGNqc6j.nunit --result=E:\BuildAgent\temp\buildTmp\FnDjYhVytEZUfv5WbP6BFfjbQiGNqc6j.nunit.xml --noheader --where cat==Unit --framework=net-4.0 --process:Multiple --agents:8
```

I however see the same command line (with .nunit filename variations) the same number of times in the build log, as I have assemblies. I'd like to invoke NUnit once, passing all my assemblies, so that NUnit can manage the parallel test execution.

Comment: What was you basis that TeamCity is calling nunit3-console once per assembly? TC currently runs multiple test assemblies sequentially by default due to this bug: https://github.com/nunit/nunit-console/issues/116 That should still only result in a single call to nunit3-console though. Adding `--process=multiple` should force it to run in parallel - can you add the command lines you've tried to the question?

Comment: I have 30 assemblies. When I look through the build log I find 30 instances of `Starting: C:\BuildAgent\tools\nunit-console_v3.6.1\bin\nunit3-console.exe E:\BuildAgent\temp\buildTmp\FnDjYhVytEZUfv5WbP6BFfjbQiGNqc6j.nunit `

Where the .nunit file name is different for each.

Comment: Thanks for the update. Sounds like your issue is TC side, rather than NUnit - afraid it's not a product I use.

Comment: Yes, I am convinced the issue is how TC invokes NUnit, I can run it locally from command line just fine, and have the assemblies executed in parallel.